# Angular2 rc1, where is shims_for_IE

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

There used to be `shims_for_IE` in Angular2 package, but since rc1 it's removed. So what's the workaround to support IE9+ ?

Error in IE 11 with rendering mode set to Edge:

```
Error: SyntaxError: Syntax error
       at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke  (http://localhost:11111/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:321:14)
       at Zone.prototype.run (http://localhost:11111/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:18)
       at Anonymous function (http://localhost:11111/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:18)
    Evaluating http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js
    Error loading http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js
```

Error in IE 11 with rendering mode set to IE 9:

```
File: script
Error: Expected ';'
    Evaluating http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js
    Error loading http://localhost:51592/Scripts/script.js
   {
      [functions]: ,
      description: "Expected ';'
    Evaluating http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js
    Error loading http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js",
      message: "Expected ';'
    Evaluating http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js
    Error loading http://localhost:11111/Scripts/script.js",
      name: "Error",
      originalErr: { },
      stack: null
   }
```

The `script.js` generated from `script.ts` as `es6`:

```
/// <amd-module name="script" />
System.register("script", ['@angular/core', '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
        var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
        return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
    };
    var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
    };
    var core_1, platform_browser_dynamic_1;
    var script;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (core_1_1) {
                core_1 = core_1_1;
            },
            function (platform_browser_dynamic_1_1) {
                platform_browser_dynamic_1 = platform_browser_dynamic_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            let script = class script {
                constructor(element) {
                    this.loginUrl = '';
                    this.antiForgeryName = '';
                    this.antiForgeryValue = '';
                    this.loginError = '';
                    this.submitted = false;
                    this.loginUrl = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginurl');
                    this.antiForgeryName = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('antiforgeryname');
                    this.antiForgeryValue = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('antiforgeryvalue');
                    this.loginError = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginError') == null ? "" : element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginError');
                }
            };
            script = __decorate([
                core_1.Component({
                    selector: 'script',
                    templateUrl: '/Home/ScriptTemplate.html'
                }), 
                __metadata('design:paramtypes', [core_1.ElementRef])
            ], script);
            exports_1("script", script);
            platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap(script);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=script.js.map
```

**Update**

So changing to follwing solves the issue which means shims are needed:

```
 ...
 var script = function script() {
     function() constructor(element) {
        this.loginUrl = '';
        this.antiForgeryName = '';
        this.antiForgeryValue = '';
        this.loginError = '';
        this.submitted = false;
        this.loginUrl = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginurl');
        this.antiForgeryName = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('antiforgeryname');
        this.antiForgeryValue = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('antiforgeryvalue');
        this.loginError = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginError') == null ? "" : element.nativeElement.getAttribute('loginError');
     }
 };
 ...
```

But this looks like `es3` transpile, which thanks to typescript is super impossible as i have tried every single `.d.ts` out there and it still complains promise not found, set not found, etc...
see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7280

Comment: Do you have plunker?

Comment: In plunkr your can't have `ts` that's compiled to `js` then fed to Angular2. You could pass `ts` directly to Angular2 but that defeats the point here as this error won't happen (aka transpile in browser).

Comment: you could run this code separately in JScript debugger embedded in windows, but that won't help much either, since there has to be shims for IE as it won't understand `es6` syntax.

Comment: I have an RC1 plunker I wrote for an unrelated issue, I just ran this in IE, I assume it's no longer needed explicit .js file required. http://plnkr.co/edit/cVLFb26LBZY9JqZGfNiu?p=preview. Run my plunker in IE -- it works as I'd expect it to...

Comment: It does because your plunk is transpiling in browser. Check my update, this is because of missing shims. I'm not sure where to get it from as the beta shims don't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix. Download the `Typings` folder from beta.15 and place it under your project, then use `browser.d.ts` or simply downgrade to beta.15. Although I've seen solutions by installing typings package, it didn't work for me in Visual Studio.